# See Amazon shipment cost without disclosing personal information

Tags: amazon

Why does Amazon.com require me to enter my financial information before letting me see shipment costs?

Attaching some screenshots for those who do not believe.
[image: What product page looks like. No shipment cost estimate]

[image: What product page looks like. No shipment cost estimate]

[image: Proceeding to checkout requires credit card data]

Comment: Are you sure they don't just require your address? What country are you in and which amazon site are you visiting? (amazon.com?)

Comment: You said in a reply that it asks for your ZIP code and you live outside of the US. Silly question - have you specified that you're located from a region other than the United States? Additionally, try and visit the domain for your country and view the product there, ex: if you're from the UK, go to amazon.co.uk - I apologize if there's something I missed in the screen shots, I can't view them right now.

Comment: To provide shipping address you need to log in to your account. But then you will not be able to estimate shipment cost.. Unless you also provide financial information and basically almost-confirm a payment. If you do not login to an account, you can only use ZIP codes to estimate the shipment cost. As a user, this is way too much hassle for me, and smells  of dirty marketing. I mean why should I do a research a find out the regional domain prefix and use incognito mode on top of that just to see how much something will cost me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log out of your account and delete all amazon.com cookies.

Then, add the item to your cart (you can do this without logging in), and click on "estimate your shipping and tax". They only require your location to do this:

[image]

Comment: Nice answer. I think Incognito mode should be enough though. Still no use for me, as it asks for a ZIP code, and I live outside of US :\